# CSS Navigation Bar within the Parallax Page

Tags: css, parallax, navigationbar

I did look for some tutorials about parallax. I want to add navigation bar on it but the results are different from what I'm expecting. I need your help.

This is the CSS code of the navigation Bar:

```
body{
        margin: 0;


    }

    .navigation{
        width: 100%;
        background: #313131;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 0px;

    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    li {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    }

    a{
        width: 150px;
        color: white;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-family: Century Gothic;
        font-weight: bold;

    }

    a:hover{
        background: #669900;
        transition: 0.6s;
    }
```

CSS Code of Parallax Page

```
@import "bourbon";

//Edit these
$farColor: #ffe4c7;
$nearColor: darken(cyan,30%);
$layer: 7; //make sure it is +1 the ammount of layer divs in the html
$perspective: 1;

    .bg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #ffe4c7;
}

.layer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  min-height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-perspective: 1px;
          perspective: 1px;
}

.parallax-group {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax-group div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ffe4c7;
  margin-top: 600px;
  background-color: #d9d1b8;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-12px) scale(13);
          transform: translateZ(-12px) scale(13);
}
.parallax-group div:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 66%, #d9d1b8 66.01%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #d9d1b8 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 66%, #d9d1b8 66.01%), linear-gradient(45deg, #d9d1b8 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-position: 222px 0px;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.parallax-group div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ffe4c7;
  margin-top: 900px;
  background-color: #b3beaa;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(11);
          transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(11);
}
.parallax-group div:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 66%, #b3beaa 66.01%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #b3beaa 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 66%, #b3beaa 66.01%), linear-gradient(45deg, #b3beaa 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-position: 77px 0px;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.parallax-group div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #ffe4c7;
  margin-top: 1200px;
  background-color: #8cab9b;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-8px) scale(9);
          transform: translateZ(-8px) scale(9);
}
.parallax-group div:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 66%, #8cab9b 66.01%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #8cab9b 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 66%, #8cab9b 66.01%), linear-gradient(45deg, #8cab9b 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-position: 117px 0px;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.parallax-group div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #ffe4c7;
  margin-top: 1500px;
  background-color: #66988d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-6px) scale(7);
          transform: translateZ(-6px) scale(7);
}
.parallax-group div:nth-child(4):before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 66%, #66988d 66.01%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #66988d 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 66%, #66988d 66.01%), linear-gradient(45deg, #66988d 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-position: 183px 0px;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.parallax-group div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #ffe4c7;
  margin-top: 1800px;
  background-color: #40867e;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-4px) scale(5);
          transform: translateZ(-4px) scale(5);
}
.parallax-group div:nth-child(5):before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 66%, #40867e 66.01%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #40867e 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 66%, #40867e 66.01%), linear-gradient(45deg, #40867e 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-position: 71px 0px;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.parallax-group div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: #ffe4c7;
  margin-top: 2100px;
  background-color: #1a7370;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
          transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}
.parallax-group div:nth-child(6):before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 66%, #1a7370 66.01%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #1a7370 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 66%, #1a7370 66.01%), linear-gradient(45deg, #1a7370 34%, transparent 34.01%);
  background-position: 13px 0px;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: "Arial";
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
          transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}

.fill {
  height: 80%;
}
```

HTML Code

```
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="parallax">

  <div class="parallax-group">

    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer fill"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Parallax Scrolling</h1>
    <p>Using only CSS</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navigation">

    <ul>

        <li><a href="Home.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="beachHouses.html"><span>Beach Houses</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="Gallery.html"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="Contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>

    </ul>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I want a floating navigation bar within the parallax page

Here is the result that I get:
https://jsfiddle.net/christiands97/s5Ltf6pj/

Answer (score 1):

Put these in the css of your `navigation` class.

```
top: 10px;
position: absolute;
```

change the `top` value according to your requirement. Also make the 'position' `fixed` if you want the navigation bar to be fixed at the top.